# $l^{1}$-distance and projection in Euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry, hilbert-spaces, analytic-geometry

Let us consider Euclidean space $H = R^{n}$ equipped with standard dot product 
$$
<x,y> = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}y_{i}
$$
and 
corresponding $l^{2}$-norm $||\cdot||_{2}$. Next, let $S$ be a vector subspace of $H$.

Let $\Pi(h|S)$ be an orthogonal projection of $h\in H$ onto $S$, i.e.

$$
\Pi(h|S) = argmin_{x\in S}||h - x||_{2}
$$

Assume that $g\in S$ is some vector from $S$. Can you give an example of $S$, $g \in S$ and $h \in H$ but $h \notin S$ such that

$$
||h - g||_{1} < ||\Pi(h|S) - g||_{1},
$$
where $||\cdot||_{1}$ is $l^{1}$-norm.

Comment: edit: $h \notin S$ is a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider H = $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S = <(u,v)>.$ $\, (u^2 + v^2 = 1)$

define $h = (a,b)$ and  $g = (u,v)$. then our criterion will be

$$
\|a-u,b-v\|_1 < |au+bv-1|\|u,v\|_1\\i.e.\quad|a-u|+|b-v|<|au+bv-1|(|u|+|v|)
$$

By setting $ s = a- u,\,\, t = b - v$,

$$
\quad|s|+|t|<|su+tv|(|u|+|v|)
$$

Now, **assume $s = 1$** . Moreover, since $\, u^2 + v^2 = 1$, set $u = cos\theta $ and $ v = sin\theta$. 
$$
\quad|1|+|t|<|cos\theta+tsin\theta|(|cos\theta|+|sin\theta|)
$$

you can check $(t,\theta) = (7,1(rad))$ satisfies above inequality.

Equivalently, $g = (u,v) = (0.5403,0.8415)$ and $h = (a,b) = (1.5403,7.8415)$.

Comment: could you, please, clarify, what the $S$ is? In the question $S$ is a subspace, not just a subset.

Comment: S is 1d subspace of R2 plane generated by (u,v). It is common notation equivalent with {t(u,v) | t is all real number}... // Well it was same with your inner product notation.

Comment: May I show you about more details?